# SWT: How to getSelectionCount from a CCombo control?

Tags: eclipse, combobox, swt

From a TEXT i can do it through:

```
((Text)control).getSelectionCount();
```

But, how can i access it on a CCombo?

```
((CCombo)control).getSelectionCount(); is not implemented...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the implementation of `Text.getSelectionCount()` it's trivial to do:

```
Point selection = myCCombo.getSelection();
int selectionCount = selection.y - selection.x;
```

You can also implement your own `MyCCombo`:

```
class MyCCombo extends CCombo {
   ...
   public int getSelectionCount() {
      Point selection = getSelection();
      return selection.y - selection.x;
   }
}
```

Comment: I always looked at "Point" as a "pixel" notation... shame on me to miss the Text.getSelectionCount() code... Thanks!